# 4 types of RESTful web services

Tags: web-services, rest, restful-architecture

Lately I am hearing from different sources of "different types of RESTful web services".

In particular: "4 types of RESTful web services". What are the differences between them?

Comment: CRUD = POST, GET, PUT/PATCH, DELETE

Comment: @YuanZ Those are verbs, not web services, and that mapping is not correct. PUT can be used to create resources, and POST can be used for just about anything.

Comment: What "sources"? You need to provide more context.

Comment: Lol, at least it sounded interesting. I was getting curious, never heard of the four type. :D

Answer (score 0):

POST, GET, PUT/PATCH, DELETE
Yes, sure. Simple. But I did not know that this is what it was referring to